# Не закрывается в мобильном виде меню bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

[Есть сайт](http://notabene-ykt.ru/)

С самого начала не работает мобильное меню, открывать он открывает, а вот обратно закрыть не может. Стили не трогал, в js не лез.

Как исправить?

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav id="menu" class="navbar gffg">
<div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">{{ text_category }}</span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=product/category&path=65" class="dropdown-toggle">Каталог</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" >
    <div class="dropdown-inner">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    {% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.children %}

    <li class="dropdown dropdown-toggle"><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle submenu1">{{ category.name }}</a>
      {% if category.column == 1 %}
        {% set box_child = 'level3' %}
      {% elseif category.column >= 2 %}
        {% set box_child = 'level3' %}
      {% endif %}
      <div class="dropdown-menu" style="left: 185px;margin-top: -29px;">
        <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            {% for child in children %}
            <li class="{{ box_child }}">
              {% if butik_category_thumb and child.thumb %}
                <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><img src="{{ child.thumb }}" alt="{{ child.name }}" class="category-img" /></span>
              {% endif %}
              {% if child.sub_children %}
                <a href="{{ child.href }}" class="submenu1">{{ child.name }}</a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled level3">
                  {% for sub_child in child.sub_children %}
                  <li><a href="{{ sub_child.href }}" > {{ sub_child.name }}</a></li>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              {% else %}
                <a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a>
              {% endif %}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          {% endfor %}</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li><a href="{{ category.href }}" fgfg>{{ category.name }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if menu_link_add is not empty %}
    {% for key, value in menu_link_add %}
    <li><a href="{{ value.link }}">{{ value.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown dropdown-toggle"><a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=39" class="dropdown-toggle submenu1">Где купить</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">

            <li>
              <a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=5">Адреса салонов         
              </a>
              </li>
              <li>
             <a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=6">Заказ и доставка         
              </a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-toggle"><a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=40" class="dropdown-toggle submenu1">Интернет-журнал NB!</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">

            <li>
              <a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=9">История здоровья        
              </a>
              </li>
              <li>
             <a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=extension/d_blog_module/category&category_id=8">Новости NB!        
              </a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                             <a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=extension/d_blog_module/category&category_id=10">На заметку!        
              </a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-toggle"><a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=41" class="dropdown-toggle submenu1">NOTA BENE!</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
           <li>
              <a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=extension/d_blog_module/category&category_id=9">Акции и скидки    
              </a>
              </li>
            <li>
              <a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4">О компании     
              </a>
              </li>
              <li>
             <a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=7">Сотрудничество       
              </a>
            </li>

                              <li>
             <a href="http://notabene-ykt.ru/index.php?route=information/contact">Контакты        
              </a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    {% if butik_html_block_status1 %}
    <li class="dropdown html-block hidden-sm hidden-xs">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{ html_title1 }}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          {{ html_content1 }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if butik_html_block_status2 %}
    <li class="dropdown html-block hidden-sm hidden-xs">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{ html_title2 }}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          {{ html_content2 }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
   {% endif %}
    {% if butik_html_block_status3 %}
    <li class="dropdown html-block hidden-sm hidden-xs">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{ html_title3 }}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          {{ html_content3 }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if butik_information_status %}
    {% if informations %}
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{ text_information }}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            {% for information in informations %}
            <li><a href="{{ information.href }}">{{ information.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if butik_contact_status %}
    <li><a href="{{ contact }}">{{ text_contact }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
```

Comment: Нужен код, что тут советовать...

Comment: @Fox вроде как ссылку добавил, но на всякий вставил код

Comment: Я смотрю, у Вас там подключение jquery, bootstrap идёт и в хеде, и ещё в футере зачем-то. Плюс какой-то bootsnav подключен. Может быть, в этом проблема. Попробуйте в хеде оставить только стили, а в футере - только скрипты (ну, или всё в хед перенести). Без дублирования.

Comment: @humster_spb действтильно, не заметил этого как так произошло, спасибо заработало